# Synchronize lists on two separate sites

Tags: list-view

In my organization, we have a sharepoint site for my department where we add to and manage a list (we'll call it List A) of all our currenet projects.

There is a manager who needs to aggregate project lists for all departments on a separate sharepoint site (including a list for my department, which on his site we'll call List B).

What is the best way to keep List B synchronized with List A?

Comment: Do users need to edit list B?

Comment: Are the two sites in the same Site Collection?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Custom Schedule Job, [Timer Job](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc406686%28office.12%29.aspx) or [PowerShell](http://jespermchristensen.wordpress.com/2008/09/11/sharepoint-list-synchronization-with-powershell-1-0/) (also PowerShell [script](http://splistsync.codeplex.com/) on CodePlex ) as described [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopmentprevious/thread/29b77708-5b6f-4899-aaa6-27ef8114ebe1/).

There is also [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee535526%28v=office.14%29.aspx)`s article on this. An article on [Microsoft Sync Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee536628%28v=office.14%29.aspx) can be found there, as well.

Also, [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/93558/Displaying-a-SharePoint-List-from-another-team-sit) is a Tutorial by Raymund Macaalay on how it can be done.